# Is there a way to create a new input type in android edit text?

Tags: android, input, types, android-edittext

I wanted to know if there was a way to create your own input type, which will be usable in your edit text.
Like for example I want to force the user to only put numbers between 1 and 5, so the input type "number" doesn't feet with what I want, and I would like to create a new input type which would be "number_1_5" and only allow the user to add a number between 1 and 5.

I searched in the android docs, and on the web but found nothing :(

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try to use text change listener and on change check if the number is between 1 to 5.

Comment: I think you can use from `InputFilter`  for this purpose.

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I wanted to do but I just didn't realize that I could do that with it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use from `InputFilter` for this purpose:

```
 InputFilter filter= new InputFilter() {

    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
            String checkMe = String.valueOf(source.charAt(i));

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[12345]*");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(checkMe);
            boolean valid = matcher.matches();
            if(!valid){
                Log.d("", "invalid");
                return "";
            }
        } 
        return null; 
    } 
};

mEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```